# Mocha unit testing mock variables in javascript

Tags: testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing test cases for Javascript using mocha. My code exactly looks like this [apigee](https://community.apigee.com/articles/3964/unit-testing-javascript-code-with-mocha-sinon-and.html)

This javascript is deployed in apigee cloud. Where it has access to platform variables. This is myscript my-code.js

```
    var responseCode = parseInt(context.getVariable(properties.source));

var log = {
    org: context.getVariable(organization.name),
    env: context.getVariable(environment.name),
    responseCode: responseCode,
    isError: (responseCode >= 400)
};

if (log.isError) {
    log.errorMessage = context.getVariable(flow.error.message);
}

var logglyRequest = new Request(
        'https://loggly.com/aaa', 
        'POST', 
        {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
        JSON.stringify(log)
);
httpClient.send(logglyRequest);
```

javascript code would have access to properties.source at run time. Apigee platform has its own internal way of how jc access those params. My question is if I am writing test case for this jc, how would I mock the values for properties.source. I am able to mock function call context.getVariable(). I am getting ReferenceError: properties is not defined. Test script in same in the apigee link given.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument of `context.getVariable()` be of String type like this? `parseInt(context.getVariable('properties.source'))`

Comment: No. It should be without quotes. I have tried this and it needs it that way.

Comment: Ok, the example in the link you provided had quotes. If that's the case, you have to define what `properties.source` is. The variable isn't defined. You don't need sinon to define an object. Just do `let properties = { "source": "response.status.code" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your tests:

```
global.properties = {
  source: 'jwt.Decode-IAM-JWT.decoded.header.kid'
};
```

That is what I do and it works fine.